# Automated copy and paste?

Tags: lyx, automation, copy-paste

I have found a program that can convert PDF to LaTeX, and so I have `.tex` files of various math textbooks. I want to make a list of theorems from the book, and so I have been manually copying and pasting from the `.tex` file. Is there any way I can automate this process? For example, I could copy every line/paragraph that starts with the word theorem. Specifically, I am using LyX.

Comment: grep "^theorem" filename.tex > extracted.tex would find all lines beginning with 'theorem'. If you want to find 'TheOReM' as well, try grep -i "^theorem" instead.

Comment: @cfr He is asking for paragraphs as well, which should be multiline in the LaTeX source,  so `grep "^theorem"` is not likely to produce the desired result.

Comment: Depends on your source, I guess. My paragraphs would be seen as single lines in the source (usually). If you have your editor hard wrap or manually introduce line breaks then it would not work. sed or gawk would work better in that case. My point really is that trying to do this in your editor is probably a mistake.

Comment: By the way, what are you using to convert pdf to latex?

Comment: You can use Emacs and AUCTeX to record a macro to process your files. If you play your cards right, you can get the job done very, very quickly (matter of minutes). You could then import the TeX source into LyX.

Comment: @cfr: I used inftyreader

Comment: The `\extract` package (http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extract/extract.pdf) can write the `theorem` environments in a tex file to another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not play nice with LyX (I haven't tested),
  but here is a solution to strip specific environments
  from a source file into a destination file.
Define the function:

```lisp
(require 'cl) ; place your cursor after this paren and pres C-x C-e

(defun **strip-stuff (file &optional environments)
  "Takes the current file and strips every environment from
`ENVIRONMENTS` into `FILE`."
  (interactive "FFile name: \nxList of Environments (\"one\" \"two\" \"etc\"): ")
  (if (every 'stringp environments)
      (progn
        (beginning-of-buffer)
        (let ((search-regex (concat "\\\\begin{"
                                    (mapconcat 'identity
                                               environments
                                               "\\|")
                                    "}")))
          (while (search-forward-regexp search-regex nil t)
            (LaTeX-mark-environment)
            (copy-region-as-kill (point) (mark))
            (save-excursion
              (find-file file)
              (end-of-buffer)
              (yank)
              (newline 2)
              (save-buffer)
              (previous-buffer))
            (exchange-point-and-mark)))
        (message "Strip complete.  Check %s for the output." file))
    (message (concat "The environment variable you provided"
                     " was not a list of strings.")))) ; here too
```

and just apply it (`M-x **strip-stuff`) within your file.

I've posted a video example of this working [on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8QddgnkMz4).
It demonstrates how to apply the function
  to multiple files automatically using a simple keyboard macro.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a TeX related question. If you want to cut and paste just few paragraphs you will want to familiarize yourself with a serious text editor. I use nvi but typically you would want to check Vim and Emacs before considering other editors. For mass automation you will want to use at the very list to learn sed (streaming editor) and shell script or some kind a scripting language (Perl, Python comes to mind).
Learning regular expressions is assumed.

Note that lack of native scripting language will render Windows OS useless for any serious text processing so you will have to use some kind UNIX or UNIX-like OS.

Disclaimer: I have heard for PowerShell for Windows but never really done anything serious with that OS.

Comment: There is Emacs for windows. I just don't know how applicable this is to the question; PDF is not particularly text-based.

Comment: @Sean Check his question again. He wants to cut and paste .tex source files. There is no Emacs for Windows. Check out you installation and you will see bunch of Cygwin stuff installed so that you can use Emacs on Windows. The same goes for Vin for Windows and so on. Python probably feels the most natural of all above tools on Windows but I started using computer long before Windows existed so I could not care less.

Comment: I don't have my installation near me (and won't until I return to campus) but it is not a minimal Cygwin or mingw install (I believe). My point was Emacs can be used on windows; you don't have to have a unix OS. If Emacs doesn't do the truck on its own, Cygwin is available. I can vouch that Powershell is effectively useless.

Comment: I did miss some content in the question. Again I don't have my computer and can't post a proper answer, but I'll leave a comment up top.

Comment: It is not really a TeX related question because the only good solutions are likely to involve generic text-processing tools. That is, as these comments show, platform specific. perl is available for Windows. TeX Live uses it.

Comment: Ok so do you guys recommend I get some unix OS? I have windows and apparently I can't do as much with it. So should I get a virtual machine? also, @SeanAllred, can I use AUCTeX on windows?

Comment: @1mathboy1, yes, AUCTeX can be used with any Emacs.  Windows isn't as versatile as unix-y OSes, but it will work just fine for this use.  I would ask this question on SU, though.

Comment: @SeanAllred Ok, I got AUCTeX installed on my windows computer with Emacs, following the directions on their website. Do you know of any good tutorials? Specifically, I want to copy everything starting from any line beginning with "definition," "theorem," "corollary," "proposition," and stop copying when it gets to "proof" or "example" or "remark."

Comment: @1mathboy1 Let's not needlessly bother poor Pedrag… [let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12251/discussion-from-comments)